# Select checkbox by substring of custom data attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, selector, custom-data-attribute

How can i select checkbox which contains number in range of numbers (numbers are not repeated) in data attribute. Lets say i have these two checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="A" data-numbers="1,3,2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="B" data-numbers="34,21,11,39,8,6,33" />
```

and i want to select checkbox by number 3.

Because number 3 is second number in first checkbox data-numbers, it should match and select first checkbox.

Comment: change to array format `data-numbers="[1,2,3]"` and jQuery.data() will parse as array automatically, then use array methods

Answer (score 3):

You can filter the jQuery objects.

```
var num = "3";
var elem = $('[date-numbers]').filter(function(){
   return $(this).data("numbers").split(",").indexOf(num) > -1;
});
```

What you're doing is filtering based on splitting on `,` and then checking if the `num` is present in it.

Comment: For some reason, it gives me "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined". But when i console.log($(this).data('numbers')) it shows me those numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses the same technique as @AmitJoki's but transfers some *processing* to the markup, if you're open to suggestions. By changing `"1,3,2"` to `"[1,3,2]"` ....., the code becomes:

```
var num = 3;
$(':checkbox').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('numbers').indexOf( num ) > -1;
})
.prop('checked', true); //or whatever other processing you'd like to perform
```

```js
$(function() {
    //not required .. just for demo purposes
    $(':checkbox').after(function() {
        return $('<label/>', {text: $(this).data('numbers')});
    });

    var num = 3;
    $(':checkbox').filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('numbers').indexOf( num ) > -1;
    })
    .prop('checked', true); //or whatever other processing you'd like to perform
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="A" data-numbers="[1,3,2]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="B" data-numbers="[34,21,11,39,8,6,33]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all inputs with 'data-numbers' set the attr checked if the index of your value to located is found

```
$("input[data-numbers]").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("checked", $(this).attr('data-numbers').indexOf(",3,") > -1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/jfzpakru/